# Transform.SetParent won't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

i am trying to give an object as a child of another after beeing instanciated but nothing seem to do it, (you will find my essays as commented codes)

```
 void Update()
 {  
        if (!isCreated)
        {
                if ( GameObject.Find("blue").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude == 0 
                &&(Time.time >1))
            {
                Instantiate (indice, new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.localPosition.x + 0.5f ,
                                                  gameObject.transform.localPosition.y + 2,
                                                  gameObject.transform.localPosition.z ),
                                 Quaternion.identity);
                Debug.Log (this.GetComponent<Item>().name.ToString());
                //indice.SetActive(false);
                //indice.transform.SetParent(this.GetComponent<Item>().transform, true);
                indice.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find(this.name.ToString()).transform, false);
                //indice.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                //indice.name = this.transform.name.ToString()+"ItemIndice";
//              GameObject.Find(indice.name).SetActive(false);
                isCreated=true;
                gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
                gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().isTrigger = true;
            } 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You instantiate new object but not assign it. You can check `Instantiate` from [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

```
 Instantiate (indice, new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.localPosition.x + 0.5f ,
                                       gameObject.transform.localPosition.y + 2,
                                       gameObject.transform.localPosition.z ),
                                       Quaternion.identity);
```

So You can use this

```
GameObject newIndice = Instantiate (indice, new Vector3 (gameObject.transform.localPosition.x + 0.5f ,
                                            gameObject.transform.localPosition.y + 2,
                                            gameObject.transform.localPosition.z ),
                                            Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

Then after that you can set parent object to newIndice. Like

```
newIndice.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
```

Comment: thats what i did but did not work :) never the less i changed my mind and i did it anothr way and it is working :

when i specified for each instance a new object i had the possibility to act for every item apart and it allawed me to setactive them false or true as i whished thank you